# Conditional expectation and Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider the canonical Markov Chain in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with transition kernel
$$K(x,dy)=\frac{1}{2d} \sum_{e \in \mathbb{Z}^d,|e|=1} \delta_{x+e}(dy)$$ corresponding to a simple random walk  (In particular, the $\theta_n$ are the shift operators on the underlying probability space $\Omega$. In trying to prove that $X_n-X_{n-1}$ are iid and uniformly distributed on $V=\{v\in \mathbb{Z}^d: |v|=1\}$,  the lecturer claims the following equalities
$$\begin{align}P_x[X_1-X_0=v_1,\ldots,X_n-X_{n-1}=v_n] &= \\
E^{P_x}[X_1-X_0=v_1,\ldots,\mathbb{1}_{\{X_1-X_{0}=v_n\}}\circ \theta_{n-1}] \\
 \end{align} $$

I already have a problem with this, since to me the right hand side should be:

$$E^{P_x}[\mathbb{1}_{\{X_1-X_0=v_1\}}\cdots \mathbb{1}_{\{X_1-X_{0}=v_n\}}\circ \theta_{n-1}]$$
Then he computes $E^{P_x}[\mathbb{1}_{\{X_1-X_{0}=v_n\}}\circ \theta_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=\frac{1}{2d}$
and claims that
$$ \begin{align} E^{P_x}[X_1-X_0=v_1,\ldots,\mathbb{1}_{\{X_1-X_{0}=v_n\}}\circ \theta_{n-1}] &= \\
E^{P_x}[X_1-X_0=v_1,\ldots,\mathbb{1}_{\{X_{n-1}-X_{n-2}=v_{n-1}\}}] \frac{1}{2d} \end{align} $$

I don't get this. How can he pass from expectation to conditional expectation just like that?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \, \mid \, \mathcal{G}))$ if $\mathcal{G}$ is any $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss that... What do you think about what is happening in the first equation instead?

Comment: I mean, what sense does the expectation of an event make? They ought to be indicator functions.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that it's a typo and your suggested fix looks like what was intended.